# get a function from a service Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I use a function in a component that is in a service? I am trying to use:

```
 addProyecto(proyecto: Proyecto) {
    this.proyectosCollection.add(this.proyecto);
}
```

but it returns this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at ProyectosService.addProyecto`

What I want is to add a document in a collection of Firestore, I can do it from the same component but I can not do it using a service.

Any ideas?

**proyecto.ts**

```js
export interface Proyecto {
    titulo?: string;
    destacado?: string;
    descripcion?: string;
}

export interface ProyectoId extends Proyecto {
    id: string
};
```

**proyecto.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Proyecto } from './proyecto';

//Firestore
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class ProyectosService {

    proyecto: Proyecto = {};
    proyectosCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Proyecto>;
    proyectosObservable: Observable<Proyecto[]>;

    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { 

    }

    getProyectos() {
        this.proyectosCollection = this.afs.collection('proyectos', ref => ref.orderBy('titulo'));

        this.proyectosObservable = this.proyectosCollection.snapshotChanges().map(arr => {
            return arr.map(snap => {
                const data = snap.payload.doc.data() as Proyecto;
                const id = snap.payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
            });
        });
        return this.proyectosObservable;
    };

    addProyecto(proyecto: Proyecto) {
        this.proyectosCollection.add(this.proyecto);
    }

}
```

**crear-proyecto.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProyectosService } from '../proyectos.service';
import { Proyecto } from '../proyecto';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-crear-proyecto',
    templateUrl: './crear-proyecto.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./crear-proyecto.component.scss'],
    providers: [ProyectosService]
})
export class CrearProyectoComponent implements OnInit {


    proyecto: Proyecto = {};
    proyectosCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Proyecto>;
    proyectosObservable: Observable<Proyecto[]>;

    constructor(private sp: ProyectosService, private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    agregarProyecto() {
        this.sp.addProyecto(this.proyecto)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.proyectosCollection` is undefined becuase you defined it inside a function `getProyectos()`. It will be undefined until this function get called.

Move your collection to `ngOnInit()` in **proyecto.service.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.proyectosCollection = this.afs.collection('proyectos', ref => ref.orderBy('titulo'));
}
```

and your get function look like this

```
getProyectos() {
    this.proyectosObservable = this.proyectosCollection.snapshotChanges().map(arr => {
        return arr.map(snap => {
            const data = snap.payload.doc.data() as Proyecto;
            const id = snap.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
        });
    });
    return this.proyectosObservable;
};
```

now you can call `addProyecto()`

Comment: I tried but it generates an empty document, that is, it only generates the ID but without any content.

Comment: in your add function try `this.afs.collection('proyectos').add(this.proyecto);`

Comment: I still generate the empty document, my only option is to do it in the same component.

Comment: i think you should do `this.afs.collection('proyectos').add(proyecto);` and `this.proyecto` is defined empty at the top